# Autoscrolling of page after page load in Angular

Tags: html, angular, autoscroll

I have to autoscroll my page at the bottom

**Code for scrolling**

```
window.scrollTo({ left: 0, top: 20 * window.outerHeight, behavior: 'smooth' });
```

It is working perfectly fine, when using this with click event.

But when I'm putting that block of code in constructor, it's not working

```
this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      let ref = params['ref'];
      console.log(ref); 
      if(ref=="subscription"){
        window.scrollTo({ left: 0, top: 20 * window.outerHeight, behavior: 'smooth' });
      }
    });
```

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: try AfterViewInit
lifecycle hook.https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit

Comment: tried this, but still facing the same issue

Comment: which version of angular are you using

Comment: i am using Angular4

Comment: Angular 6+ there is a new feature called ViewportScroller which will fix your problem i guess.Check this:https://angular.io/api/common/ViewportScroller

Comment: @Chellappan i found in app.component.ts there is a block of code written for scrolltotop . So, is there a way to override this

Answer (score 0):

You can handle in 'NavigationEnd' Router Events also. Here is the block of code we added in app.component.ts and it works

```
router.events.pipe(pairwise()).subscribe((event: [NavigationEnd, NavigationEnd]) => {
  if (event[0] instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    window.scroll(0, 0);
  }
}
```